# Making a select choice result in a popup in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, popup

So this is using `javascript` and `HTML`.

For example:

```
<select name='test' >
    <option value='1'>
    <option value='2'>
    <option value='3'>
</select>
```

If someone chooses option value 2 (from the dropdown) I want a popup to appear.  However if they choose option value 1 or option value 3 (from the dropdown) I want nothing to happen.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Add an id to the select (`<select name='test' id='test'>`). Then add (after the `<select>`):

```
<script>
document.getElementById("test").onchange = function(){
    if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == '2') {
        alert('hello world!');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for separating the controller (javascript) from the Model/View (HTML)

Answer (score 0):

You can do an event handler like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pop(a) {
    if (a.value==2) alert('two');
}

</script>
```

and for the html:

```
<select id="sel" onchange="pop(this)">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

With something like this:

```
<select name='test' onchange='if(this.value==2) alert("TEST")'>
    <option value='1'>
    <option value='2'>
    <option value='3'>
</select>
```